# What is ActiveStorage's 'attach' doing behind the scenes when files are uploaded to a service as like AWS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, service, rails-activestorage

I can't seem to find a detailed explanation of what process the `attach` method initialises when uploading a file (not direct upload) to a configured service such as Amazon S3.

- Does the file get uploaded to the application server temporarily first while a job is created to upload it to S3?
- If so, is there a job to clear it out or is it removed once the job uploading it to S3 returns successfully?
- What if that job fails, does it just replace itself?  etc etc

I think I understand the process for direct uploads and why a bit of manual error handling needs to be done, but I'd like to know exactly how `ActiveStorage` handles uploads through the application server and I can't seem to find solid documentation on this.